# Giving properties of a UIButton to a SKSpriteNode in SpriteKit

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I was wondering if there was a way to give the properties of a `UIButton` like darkening the button once it has been pressed,... to a `SKSpiteNode` since an `SKSpiteNode` has more customization and because I am using `SpriteKit`. I have seen 1 other question like this but none of the answers worked. Here is the code I have to create the `SKSpriteNode` and to detect a touch on it:

```
import SpriteKit
class StartScene: SKScene {    
var startButton = SKSpriteNode()
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    startButton = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "playButton")
    startButton.size = CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)
    startButton.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.width / 2, y: self.frame.height / 2 - 50)
    self.addChild(startButton)
}
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    /* Called when a touch begins */

    for touch in touches {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)

        if startButton.containsPoint(location){
           // When it has been selected
        }   
    }
}
//...
```

Pleas help. Thanks in advance... Anton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have always achieved this by adding code to the touches began, and touches ended method.  Inside of these methods I simply set the sprites color to black, and then change its color blend factor.  Let me know if this works for you!

```
  //This will hold the object that gets darkened
    var target = SKSpriteNode() 
    //This will keep track if an object is darkened
    var have = false

override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
var first = touches.first as! UITouch
        var location:CGPoint = first.locationInNode(self)
        touchP = location
        mouse.position = touchP
        var node:SKNode = self.nodeAtPoint(location)
       if let button = node as? SKSpriteNode
       {
          target = button
           have = true
       }
       else
       {
         have = false
       }

       if (have == true)
       {
           target.color = UIColor.blackColor()
           target.colorBlendFactor = 0.2

       }
}

override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
            if (havet == true)
            {
                target.color = UIColor.blackColor()
                target.colorBlendFactor = 0
                target = SKSpriteNode()
                have = false

            }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! Since I'm inside my gameScene.swift, it shows me this error: method does not override method from its superclass. Any help?

Comment: That is odd.   It is possible that some of my code isn't in the latest swift syntax.  Why don't you remove my code form your project.  Then type in "override func touch" and then let xcode type the rest.  Do that for touches began and touches ended, then compile.   If that causes issues then come back here and we can figure that out. If not then everything is OK and you can copy the bits of my code except for use your function lines of code not mine (just paste the body of it)

Comment: I fixed the error that I just had but I didn't test the rest. I will do this now

Comment: I see that adding touches ended could possibly resolve my problem! If I have anymore problem concerning this code, I will ask you but for now, great answer!