# How to make Buttons with effect in SpriteKit and Swift?

Tags: swift, animation, sprite-kit

Hey guys I have another question. It seems to me that the only way to make a button in SpriteKit is to use the `touchesBegan` function, which is great but the buttons are pretty lame because they have no animation and no effect when you touch them. All great games I know that are made with SpriteKit — for example "100 Balls" — have a cool effect when you press the button and then when you release it, you go to the next scene for example. Especially Candy Crush Saga got some very nice bounce effects but I think that they don't use SpriteKit. But anyways, my question is how do they make those buttons with effects? (sorry for my bad english :/)

Comment: You can try with [SKAButton](https://github.com/SpriteKitAlliance/SKAButton) or something similar to see how those work (or use it in your projects). Later on, you can implement something by yourself when become familiar with how these things works.

Comment: You are gonna have to implement your own functions to make whatever effects you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the button to become small when you press on it and big when you let go, you can implement code in your `Touches Began` and `Touches Ended` (and even `Touches Moved` if you want):
Under `Touches Began`:

```
if button.containsPoint(location){
let scale = SKAction.scaleTo(0.7, duration: 0)
button.runAction(scale)
}
```

Under `Touches Ended`:

```
if button.containsPoint(location){
let scale = SKAction.scaleTo(1, duration: 0)
button.runAction(scale)
}
```

Under `Touches Moved`:

```
if !button.containsPoint(location){
let scale = SKAction.scaleTo(1, duration: 0)
button.runAction(scale)
}
```

Btw, this is untested code. Please let me know how it goes. I've posted a question like this with more code here: [Giving properties of a UIButton to a SKSpriteNode in SpriteKit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35258342/giving-properties-of-a-uibutton-to-a-skspritenode-in-spritekit).

Good Luck!

Comment: I've also tried this and it works but normally when you press a button and you want to cancel you can just go outside the button and he goes back to normal. And in this case he would just stay at the small size you are probably not able to cancel.

Comment: You have to use touches Moved for this (use variable if you want the button to get smaller and bigger once you selected the button while touching the screen, for an example, please check my question), I will edit my answer